# jQuery - Increase textarea on click; Decrease after if not text;

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do the following:

- Textarea original have 60px height;
- On textarea click the size slides to 150px;
- If the user types text in... when leave the textarea, keep the 150px;
- If the user doesn't types text... and leave the textarea, it slides back to 60px;

Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry but why this question is downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to `focus` and `blur` events:

```js
var txt = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
txt.onfocus = function() {
  this.style.height = '150px';
};
txt.onblur = function() {
  if(this.value === this.defaultValue) {
    this.style.height = '';
  }
};
```

```css
#mytextarea {
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="mytextarea">Foo</textarea>
```

If the textarea is originally empty and you want it to go back to the original size if the user only entered spaces, in the `if` statement you can check

```js
this.value.trim() === ''
```

Comment: Great! Just a quick question... how can I also back to original size if it is only entered space? I tried originalText = $.trim(txt.value); but did not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<textarea style="height:60px;">
</textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', 'textarea', function(){
$(this).css('height', '150px');
});

$(document).on('focusout', 'textarea', function(){
var inside=$(this).val().trim();

if (inside.length){
    $(this).css('height', '150px');
}
else{
    $(this).css('height', '60px');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/UnTtR/3/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mytextarea").focus(function(){
    $("#mytextarea").animate({"height":"150px"}, 1000);
  });
  $("#mytextarea").blur(function(){
    $("#mytextarea").animate({"height":"60px"}, 1000);
  });
});
```